# How to derive the conditional given the following joint probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, monte-carlo

I encountered this question while reading about MCMC methods to solve image reconstruction problems.

Consider a black and white image where $-1$ corresponds to white and $+1$ to black. $X_{i,j}$ represents the observed image with $X_{i,j} \in \{-1, +1\}$ representing a pixel at row $i$ and column $j$. The true/unknown image, $Y_{i,j}$ with $Y_{i,j} \in \{-1, +1\}$. $Y_{i,j}$ has four immediate neighbors. E is the corresponding set of edges of the neighbors

Given the following information, how would one derive the conditional probability that a pixel $(i, j)$ is black given its Markov blanket, $P(Y_{i,j}=1|Y_{M(i,j)})$? $Y_{M(i, j)}$ represents the variables in the blanket.

Joint: $$P(y, x) = \frac{1}{Z}\{ \prod_{i=1}^N \prod_{j=1}^M exp^{\eta y_{i,j} x_{i,j}} \}{\prod_{((i,j),(i',j')) \in E} \{ exp^{\beta y_{i,j} y_{i',j'}} \} }$$

Normalizing Factor: $$z = \sum_{y,x} exp \{E(y,x) \}$$ where $E(y,x)$ is the Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: So far, this is what I have:

$$P(Y_{i,j}=1 | Y_{M(i,j)})= \frac{P(Y_{i,j}=1 , Y_{M(i,j)})}{P(Y_{i,j}=1 | Y_{M(i,j)}) + P(Y_{i,j}=-11 | Y_{M(i,j)})}$$

Where $$P(Y_{i,j} , Y_{M(i,j)}) = \frac{1}{z} \sum exp \{  \} $$

Comment: I cannot modify the above comment- $exp \{ E(x,y) \}$